# "AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'plot_width' to figure, similar attributes are outer_width, width or min_width " with pandas_bokeh

Tags: pandas, dataframe, graphing, pandas-bokeh

I am trying to use `pandas_bokeh` to create a line graph with a pandas dataframe I call `bucketed_df`

```
import pandas_bokeh
pandas_bokeh.output_notebook()

bucketed_df.plot_bokeh(kind='line')
```

for some reason I get the error

```
AttributeError: unexpected attribute 'plot_width' to figure, similar attributes are outer_width, width or min_width
```

Im not sure what this is or how toi fix it. I am using python 3.9 and jupyter notebooks

I have a matplotlib linegraph in a cell above it. I am thinking there could be some issue with that.

Also if anyone knows any interactive graphs that are better I am open to switching to a different library.

Comment: Are you able to share a sample of bucketed_df? (populated with fake data is fine as long as the types and examples are similar)

Comment: Its index is a datetime object and theres one column called id, which just contains integers.

Answer (score 9):

I'm getting a similar error on a recent install of bokeh==3.0.1.

The error goes away if I install version 2.4.3 (last release) with `pip install --upgrade bokeh==2.4.3`

It seems there was a breaking change in 3.0.0 that hasn't been addressed yet. If you have time, post this issue at https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues.

Comment: For those who come here with the `bokeh` error in their own code (I did - and this question was the first result in the search): In the `3.0.0` `bokeh` release, the `plot_width` attribute of a figure was replaced with `width`. Similarly, `plot_height` was replaced with `height`. Even in the last [2.x.x release docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/2.4.3/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html?highlight=plot_width), they are described as "compatibility aliases" for `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 4):

can be done like

```
p=figure(min_width=500, height=500)
```

or simply,

```
p=figure(width=500, height=500)
```

this may help.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

temp way:

File ".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas_bokeh/plot.py", line 439, in plot

Add

```
figure_options['width'] = figure_options['plot_width']
figure_options['height'] = figure_options['plot_height']
del figure_options['plot_width']
del figure_options['plot_height']
```

Comment: While that may work, I wonder if there is a solution that doesn't require removing features in the bokeh library

Answer (score 0):

The error has been reported in the GitHub of pandas_bokeh :
https://github.com/PatrikHlobil/Pandas-Bokeh/issues/128
But unfortunately, no solution has been found yet, except for someone using the latest commit of the github... For what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

this temp way works but you must change file
".../lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas_bokeh/geoplot.py" not plot.py

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).